# How can I efficiently query for all rows in a database matching a filter based on a joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

Apologies if the question title is unclear; I'm not sure how to phrase this without more detail.
I have a table `foos` like:

```
id (bigint) | details (json)
1           | {someKey: 'someValue' ...}
2           | {someKey: 'otherValue' ...}
...
```

I also have a table `foo_labels` like:

```
foo_id (bigint) | label_id (bigint)
1               | 10
2               | 13
...
```

I'm interested in retrieving all the foo's matching a certain label filter. For example, if I want to fetch all the foo's with the label 5 OR 6, I can do:

```
select f.* from foos f 
join foo_labels fl on f.id = fl.foo_id
where fl.label_id in (5, 6)
group by f.id
```

Similarly, I can fetch all foos with labels 5 AND 6 with something like:

```
select f.* from foos f
join foo_labels fl on f.id = fl.foo_id 
where fl.label_id in (5, 6)
group by f.id
having count(fl.label_id) = 2;
```

But I'm getting stuck with more complex queries. For example, how would I do a query to get all the foos that have (label 1 OR label 2) AND (label 3 OR label 4). More abstractly, I'd like to perform a query to fetch all the foo's having labels matching a group of OR clauses, AND'ed together, like:

> (l_{11} OR l_{12} OR ...) AND (l_{21} OR l_{22} OR ...) AND ...

I've tried playing around with it but can't find a solution that involves just one `join` of the `foo_labels` table; right now the only way I can get it to work is to perform one `join` per OR clause. Is there a way to make a query like this while only joining the `foo_labels` table once? I'm using MySql but if you know how to do this in a similar version of SQL that might also be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I do a query to get all the foos that have (label 1 OR label 2) AND (label 3 OR label 4)?

You can have conditional expressions in the `having` clause, like:

```
select f.* 
from foos f
join foo_labels fl on f.id = fl.foo_id 
where fl.label_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by f.id
having 
    max(fl.label_id in (1, 2)) = 1
    and max(fl.label_id in (3, 4)) = 1
;
```

The `where` clause is not strictly necessary, but it makes the query more efficient, by restricting the number of rows before aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

> (label 1 OR label 2) AND (label 3 OR label 4)

In general, you can do this in the `having` clause with no `where`.  The `join` to `foo` adds nothing helpful to the query.  Here is the idea:

```
select fl.foo_id
from foo_labels fl 
group by fl.foo_id
having sum( label_id in (1, 2) ) > 0 and
       sum( label_id in (3, 4) ) > 0 ;
```

This is easily extensible to more complicated combinations.